# Validating multiple attributes within a inline validator in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm aware you can validate a single attribute using an [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators) such as:

```
['country', 'validateCountry']

public function validateCountry($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!in_array($this->$attribute, ['USA', 'Web'])) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The country must be either "USA" or "Web".');
    }
}
```

But how do I go about passing in multiple attributes into the validator? ...or should I just reference them via `$this` within the validator?

Comment: I think you do not understand what is happening here. The array `['country', 'validateCountry']` basically states that validateCountry is applied to country, if you want to apply the validator function to other attribute just add `['secondAttribute', 'validateCountry']` and the validator would automatically apply the function for both `country` and `secondAttribute`

Comment: @Mr.Meshuggah Yes, I understand how it works. It works on the `country` attribute which is `$this->country`. However I need to make a custom validator function to check the `username` and `email` attributes against the database; I would prefer to pass them BOTH to a single validator rather than separately so I can just run the single query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of accessing the extra fields directly e.g using `$this->email` you could pass the additional attributes as a field in `params`, like how the [`compareValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator.html) works i.e

```
['username', 'customValidator', 'params' => ['extraFields' => 'email']]


public function customValidator($attribute, $params) {
    //access extrafields using $this->{$params['extraFields']}
}
```

Comment: That worked, but I had to do this: `['username', 'customValidator', 'params' => ['email' => 'email']]`

Answer (score 3):

In Yii2, you should write it like below:

```
['username', 'customValidator', 'params' => ['extraFields' => 'email']]
```

Comment: You have only copied the above answer, without any useful explanation.

Comment: @L.Antonelli notice the update time. I answered for Yii2 in 2015, and he edited the answer in 2016. It's he who copied my answer.